# Protecting constraints when refining a 2D Delaunay mesh

Tags: cgal

I am creating a 2D constrained triangulation of a polygon using `Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2`. The boundary of the polygon, as well as the boundaries of possible internal holes, are inserted as constraints in the triangulation.
Afterwards, I refine the triangulation calling `CGAL::refine_Delaunay_mesh_2`.

However, after the refinement some of the boundary (constrained) edges are split. Is there any way of preventing those edges of being split? Something similar to the parameter `protect_constraints` in `Polygon_mesh_processing::isotropic_remeshing`?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With the current implementation it is not possible because `Mesh_2` will try to make the the triangle mesh Delaunay by adding Steiner vertices onto the constrained edges.